# Using $each with $push is pushing whole object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

My mongodb document is

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "coid" : "testcoid",
        "cid" : "testcid"
    },
    "communications" : [
        {
            "sid" : "testsid",
            "campid" : "testcampid"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to finally add clicks field and add multiple values

```
{
        "_id" : {
            "coid" : "testcoid",
            "cid" : "testcid"
        },
        "communications" : [
            {
                "sid" : "testsid",
                "campid" : "testcampid",
                            "clicks" : {"www.google.com" , "www.facebook.com"}
            }
        ]
}
```

I am using command

```
db.messages.update({$and : [{"_id.coid" : "testcoid"}, {"communications.sid" : "testsid"}]},{ $push : {"communications.$.clicks" : {$each : ["www.google.com" , "www.facebook.com"]}}})
```

which instead gives this document

```
db.messages.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : {
        "coid" : "testcoid",
        "cid" : "testcid"
    },
    "communications" : [
        {
            "campid" : "testcampid",
            "clicks" : [
                     {
                    "$each" : [
                        "www.google1.com",
                        "www.google2.com"
                    ]
                      }

            ],
            "sid" : "testsid"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note : I need to do it with push itself not pushAll. Is there a way to do it with push and why is it updating it with $each object?

Comment: what difference will that make, if you use $pushAll, because $pushAll is solving your purpose?

Comment: it's a part of a bigger function and i do not want to copy paste that function again just for using pushAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query worked on my box, http://pastebin.com/STUjCuMd

Which mongodb version you are using?

Check this : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8303